# SQL max row value other than null

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**TABLE1**

| mach_id | optout | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16543 | NULL | 2022-09-27 |
| 16543 | YES | 2022-09-26 |
| 16543 | NO | 2022-09-25 |
| 14444 | YES | 2022-09-27 |
| 15676 | NO | 2022-09-27 |
| 15676 | YES | 2022-09-26 |
| 11111 | NULL | 2022-09-27 |
| 11111 | NULL | 2022-09-26 |

Required table

| mach_id | optout |
| --- | --- |
| 16543 | YES |
| 14444 | YES |
| 15676 | NO |
| 11111 | NULL |

I want to get the max optout value other than null if there are any other values for a mach_id based on time. If every optout value is null for mach_id optout should be null.
How can I query it?

I wrote this query but it's not working

```
  Select max(COALESCE(OPTOUT, 0)) AS optout,mach_id
from
(select OPTOUT,mach_id, time from table1)
where 
time=max(time)
group by mach_id
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to achieve it using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mach_id 
                          ORDER BY optout IS NOT NULL DESC, time DESC) = 1;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not possible on MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mach_id
                                   ORDER BY optout IS NULL, time DESC) rn
    FROM table1 t
)

SELECT mach_id, optout
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

The sort in the call to `ROW_NUMBER` places, for each group of `mach_id` records, the non null `optout` values first.  Within those subgroups, the record with the latest time is chosen.  A null `optout` record can only appear in the result set if only such null records are available.

Comment: won't that give NULL to 16543 mach_id?